# jqGrid show tooltip

Tags: php, jqgrid, tooltip

I am using jqGrid and I want to show a tooltip when the mouse is over a row. The tooltip must come from the database. I mean, I would like to show a tooltip containig the data that is in nombre hwen the mouse is over an id. I have the following code:

```
$("#list").jqGrid({
    url: 'grid.php',
    datatype: 'xml',
    mtype: 'GET',
    deepempty: true ,
    colNames: ['Id','Nombre'],
    colModel: [ 
        {name:'id', index:'id', width:55, title:false}, 
        {name:'nombre', index:'nombre', width:150, sortable:false, title:false} 
    ],
    pager: '#pager',
    rowNum: 30,
    //rowList:[10,20,30],
    sortname: 'nombre',
    sortorder: 'asc',
    viewrecords: true,
    gridview: true,
    caption: 'Examenes'
```

I read that I can use `gridComplete`, but I have no idea how to accomplish this

thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Setting the tooltip on the cell is nothing more as the setting of the `title` attribute on the corresponding cell.

The most simple and the most effective way to set tooltip (like to set any other cell attribute) is the usage of `cellattr` on the `colModel`.

What you can do is just include the tooltip text in the XML which produce the server. For example you can place an additional data for one more column of jqGrid, but *not* include the column declaration in the grid. So the XML data can be look like the following:

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<rows>
    <page>1</page>
    <total>1</total>
    <records>3</records>
    <row id='x1'>
        <cell><![CDATA[x1]]></cell>
        <cell><![CDATA[Test name 1]]></cell>
        <cell><![CDATA[Test tooltip 1]]></cell>
    </row>
    <row id='x2'>
        <cell><![CDATA[x2]]></cell>
        <cell><![CDATA[Test name 2]]></cell>
        <cell><![CDATA[Test tooltip 2]]></cell>
    </row>
    <row id='x3'>
        <cell><![CDATA[x3]]></cell>
        <cell><![CDATA[Test name 3]]></cell>
        <cell><![CDATA[Test tooltip 3]]></cell>
    </row>
</rows>
```

The corresponding jqGrid code which read the tooltip information and place it as the value of the `title` attribute will be the following:

```
$("#list").jqGrid({
    url: 'grid.php',
    colNames: ['Id', 'Nombre'],
    colModel: [
        {name: 'id', index: 'id', width: 55, title: false},
        {name: 'nombre', index: 'nombre', width: 150, sortable: false, title: false,
            cellattr: function (rowId, cellValue, rowObject) {
                return ' title="' + $(rowObject).find('cell:eq(2)').text() + '"';
            }}
    ],
    pager: '#pager',
    rowNum: 30,
    sortname: 'nombre',
    sortorder: 'asc',
    viewrecords: true,
    gridview: true,
    height: 'auto',
    caption: 'Examenes'
});
```

How shows [the corresponding demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/TooltipFromXml.htm) you will have the results which you need:

[image]

Comment: Hey, thank you very much. I did it, with your help, but I have a problem, My data is in htm format so when the tooltip shows I see <strong>hello world..etc Is there a way to eliminate the tags but have the html format in the tooltip? thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

What they mean is that you can use the `gridComplete` event to start something when rows of the grid have been loaded. I don't know which tooltip library you would like to use but I think qTip will assume your needs. I would stick to version 2, althought it's a development release I use it in production for a year now without any problem.

http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/

Then you do something like:

```
$("#list").jqGrid({
    url: 'grid.php',
    datatype: 'xml',
    mtype: 'GET',
    deepempty: true ,
    colNames: ['Id','Nombre'],
    colModel: [ 
    {name:'id', index:'id', width:55, title:false}, 
    {name:'nombre', index:'nombre', width:150, sortable:false, title:false} 
    ],
    pager: '#pager',
    rowNum: 30,
    //rowList:[10,20,30],
    sortname: 'nombre',
    sortorder: 'asc',
    viewrecords: true,
    gridview: true,
    caption: 'Examenes'
    gridComplete : function() {
      $('tr', this).each(function(key, item) {
    var rowId = $(item).prop('id');
    $(item).qTip({
       content: {
          text: 'Loading...', // The text to use whilst the AJAX request is loading
          ajax: {
         url: '/some/url.php', // URL to the local file
         type: 'GET', // POST or GET
         data: {
           'rowId' : rowId
         } // Data to pass along with your request
          }
       }        
    });
      });
    }
});
```

Be careful! I did not test it ;-) So you proberly have to do some debugging yourself ;-). You can find the documentation for qTip here http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/docs/

Cheers!

Comment: Hey, thank you!! I tried, but when I tets it, I get in the qgrid a message Loding... Im reading the documentation, but I have 2 questions, 1 some/url.php refers to? and what do you mean whit the comment //data to pass along? thank you very much!

Comment: The url /some/url is the url which should give you back the tooltip data. You pass the rowid in the request so your PHP script knows which tooltip text it has to give back. I showed you this example cause you said you want the tooltip to load from ajax. This is how it could works. The data to pass along are parameters you need to render the correct text in order to present it in the tooltip. Good luck!